# How to use body erb template in Mail gem?

Tags: ruby, email, pony

I would like to use as body in Mail erb template. It works when I set up it on Pony gem.

```
post 'test_mailer' do
  Mail.deliver do
    to ['test1@me.com', 'test2@me.com']
    from 'you@you.com'
    subject 'testing'
    body erb(:test_mailer) # this isn't working
  end
end

private

fields = [1, 2] # some array
```

**ERB file**

```
<% fields.each do |f| %>
  <%= f %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code? Is this a rails or sinatra app? Where does this `erb` function come from and does it know where to find an erb template from the symbol `:test_mailer`?

Comment: This is Sinatra app, when I switch to 'Pony' mailer it checks automatically ``views/test_mailer.erb`` file.

Comment: So you're basically trying to replace Pony with Mail in this example? http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your original Sinatra route using Pony looked something like this:

```
post 'test_mailer' do
  Pony.mail :to => ['test1@me.com', 'test2@me.com'],
            :from => 'you@you.com',
            :subject => 'testing',
            :body => erb(:test_mailer)
end
```

You can see that the email attributes here are specified by a Hash. When switching to using the Mail gem, it's attributes are defined by a block which gets called in a specific context so that these special methods are available.

I think the problem may have something to do with calling `erb` inside the block. Here's a few things you can try:

Try generating the ERB in a way that can be passed into the block:

```
post 'test_mailer' do
  email_body = erb :test_mailer, locals: {fields: fields}
  Mail.deliver do
    to ['test1@me.com', 'test2@me.com']
    from 'you@you.com'
    subject 'testing'
    body email_body
  end
end
```

Or calling ERB globally instead of using the sinatra helper:

```
post 'test_mailer' do
  context = binding
  Mail.deliver do
    to ['test1@me.com', 'test2@me.com']
    from 'you@you.com'
    subject 'testing'
    body ERB.new(File.read('views/test_mailer.erb')).result(context)
  end
end
```

Comment: And what if inside this erb file I have private method which returns an array

Comment: I don't understand how this could happen. Can you show an example of the ERB template?

Comment: Okay, I see now. Typically, you would not do it this way. Usually you assign your template variables as [instance variables within your route block](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20Variables%20in%20Templates) (`@fields = [1, 2]`). In order to pass local variables, you should pass the variables to the template in the locals hash. I have updated my code samples for your case.

Comment: thx for that. I wanted to use it from a ruby script (no sinatra or other). I came up with this and it works https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f48bdc80fa0121ad8f6a